# private is it automatic

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net if you leave out the word Private is it automatically Private

Are these two functions here both private?

```
Private Shared Function test()


End Function




Shared Function test()


End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you leave out an access specifier, the default is `Public`, when we're discussing procedures.

All of the defaults are gathered on [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms235296.aspx)

So, your second function is `Public`. A quick way you could have discovered this yourself is to open a project in Visual Studio, write these functions in a class (giving them different names), then open Object Explorer. Navigate to the functions and you can see what accessibility each of them has.